# Specifying multiple cancel options on jquery draggable elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

[image: title='element sample']

As shown from the diagram above, I only want to allow users to drag the element when they click on the region indicate as "Allow dragging" all other regions do not allow dragging indicated by "disable dragging". The following is the code that i currently have. It works fine only that I am unable to pass more than one selectors to the cancel option. I have tried passing an object and space separated sector but it won't work. What am i doing wrong? Please help.

```
    $(".e-note").draggable({
        stop: function(e, ui) {
            // alert(ui.position['top']);
        },
        cursor: 'move',
        opacity: 0.4,
        cancel: '.e-note-body', // How do i pass more than one selectors here?
        distance:20
    })
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can provide a [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) to combine several selectors:

```
cancel: '#selector1, .selector-two'
```

Note the comma (`,`) separating each selector inside the quotation marks.

Answer (score 1):

Or if you have a complex layout and very many elements that should 'cancel' the drag, you can instead of `cancel` use `handle` option:

```
handle: '.allow_drag_start'
```

This way you don't need to use `cancel` at all.

This has an additional con, that I found recently. If your site is using eg. http://touchpunch.furf.com/ to convert mouse-events to touchevents, the `cancel` really cancels everything, not only drag, but also touch device's native scroll and two-finger pinch zoom. In my case, I wanted scroll and zoom to work on all other elements but the handles.

Generally, I think that `handle` is the one that should be used and `cancel` is a bit workaround.